# SQL Server - How to Grant Read Access to ALL databases to a Login?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, permissions

I need to give a new login read access to all 300 databases on a server.  How can I accomplish this without checking 300 checkboxes in the user mapping area?

Comment: Since this is a really old question that still gets a lot of views, be aware that in SQL 2014+, `GRANT CONNECT ANY DATABASE TO <SQL_Login>;` along with `GRANT SELECT ALL USER SECURABLES TO <SQL_Login>;` is going to be much easier than the old way of doing things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One way would be to Set "Results to Text" on the query menu in SSMS then execute the below.

It doesn't actually make the change but generates a script for you to review and execute.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @user_name    SYSNAME
        , @login_name SYSNAME;

SELECT @user_name = 'user_name',
       @login_name = 'login_name'

SELECT '
    USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';

    CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@user_name)
       + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@login_name)
       + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];

    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember
      ''db_datareader'',
      ''' + QUOTENAME(@user_name) + ''';

    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember
      ''db_denydatawriter'',
      '''
       + QUOTENAME(@user_name) + '''; 

GO
'
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  database_id > 4
       AND state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

Or you could look at `sys.sp_MSforeachdb` [as here](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1626509-read-only-access-all-databases-server.html) or Aaron Bertrand's improved version [here](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

If you are not seeing all of the characters when you run this, open the Query Options for Text and check the setting for 'Maximum number of characters displayed in each column'.  Make sure this is set to a value large enough to display all characters.

Comment: Why am I hearing about this sp_msforeachdb just now?  I guess I just try and figure out everything with the tools I know.  Well, I'm adding that to the toolbox.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  This seemed to work.  I did have the copy the results of that query into textpad and replace Go with \nGo\n

Comment: @Greg - Glad it worked. Did you run it in Management Studio? If so selecting the option "Results to Text" (CTRL + T) would probably have avoided the need for the intermediate step.

Comment: The default SQL text column limit is 256 so you'll want to increase this in Query -> Query Options -> Results -> Text to avoid the generated scripts getting truncated.

Comment: The `QUOTENAME` around the username & loginname doesn't work for me (SQL2019).

Answer (score 6):

Cursor through the databases and GRANT access to each with a little t-sql.

I did not test the code below.

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') 


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE::@name to 'username'; 

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  
END
```

Comment: The t-sql to use after that point is my point of confusion.  Any pointers on that?

Answer (score 5):

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 
'Declare @name varchar(100)
 select @name = ''?''
 PRINT @name
 IF db_id(@name) > 4
 BEGIN
 USE ?
 CREATE USER [user] FOR LOGIN [user];
EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''user''
 END'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to tweak Martin Smith's answer slightly as:

1. The spaces and linebreaks resulted in not all the text being generated properly
2. The QUOTENAME in the Exec statement put in square brackets which is incorrect.

My version:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @user_name    SYSNAME
        , @login_name SYSNAME;

SELECT @user_name = 'HelpdeskUser',
       @login_name = 'Helpdesk'

SELECT 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(NAME) + ';
        CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@user_name)
       + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@login_name)
       + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'',''' + @user_name + ''';
    EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember ''db_denydatawriter'', ''' + @user_name + '''; 
GO'
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  database_id > 4
       AND state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

Otherwise works perfectly. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Databases Cursor
Declare @DbName as nvarchar(64)
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
Declare @BaseAddUserSql nvarchar(max)
Declare @BaseAddRoleSql nvarchar(max)

Set @Databases = Cursor Fast_Forward For
    select [name]
    from master..sysdatabases
    where [name] not in('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

Open @Databases
Fetch Next From @Databases Into @DbName

Set @BaseAddUserSql = 'exec sp_adduser ''LOGINNAME'''
Set @BaseAddRoleSql = 'exec sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''LOGINNAME'''


While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    Begin Try
        Set @Sql = 'Use ' + Quotename(@DbName)
        exec (@Sql)

        Set @Sql = Replace(@BaseAddUserSql, 'LOGINNAME', <loginname>)
        exec(@Sql)

        Set @Sql = Replace(@BaseAddRoleSql, 'LOGINNAME', <loginname>)
        exec(@Sql)
    End Try
    Begin Catch
    End Catch

    Fetch Next From @Databases Into @DbName
End

Close @Databases
Deallocate @Databases
```

Comment: It says it completed successfully but I don't see any changes.  The user mappings area hasn't changed.  And the login I put for <loginname> doesn't appear as a user in any of the databases.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Greg - You might want to comment out the Try-Catch blocks to see the error that is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed a user that will have access to all database with a data reader permission so i used this code:
you will need to run the result from the query btw.

```
USE [master]
GO CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\USER] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master] GO
select 'use ['+name+']
CREATE USER [DOMAIN\USER] FOR LOGIN [DOMAIN\USER]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'', N''DOMAIN\USER''
'
from sys.databases
```

if you don't want to apply it on system databases just add
where database_id > 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example **Cursor**, like this :

```
USE master
GO

DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(32)   
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @User VARCHAR(64)
SET @User = '[SQL\srvSSISAcc]' --Your User

DECLARE Grant_Permission CURSOR LOCAL FOR
SELECT name FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN Grant_Permission  
FETCH NEXT FROM Grant_Permission INTO @DatabaseName  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    SELECT @SQL = 'USE '+ '[' + @DatabaseName + ']' +'; '+ 'CREATE USER ' + @User + 
    'FOR LOGIN ' + @User + '; EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datareader'', 
    ' + @User + '; EXEC sp_addrolemember N''db_datawriter'', ' + @User + ''

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    PRINT @SQL

FETCH NEXT FROM Grant_Permission INTO @DatabaseName  
END  
CLOSE Grant_Permission  
DEALLOCATE Grant_Permission
```

More info find in my post about this topic:
http://www.pigeonsql.com/single-post/2016/12/23/Grant-User-Access-to-All-Databases