# Default read-only user for MsSql database

Tags: sql-server

We're currently using a tool (no way to change this as it is tied to a larger machine) which creates databases (not tables) on a SQL server (MSSQL 2014) on a weekly basis. These are named:

- RESULT_201801
- RESULT_201802
- ...

Over the course of one week, those databases will get filled with data until the beginning of a week where the next one will be created.

Now I need to extract specific data from all available databases. The issue which arises is, that I need to have a user which is allowed to read data from each of that databases. I could easily create that user and add it manually but doing this each week monday morning doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Is there a way to have such a user (with read-only permissions) for the whole database server? What would be the correct way to do that? Will I need to resort back to using a script, executed hourly, checking permissions?

Comment: Did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087140/sql-server-how-to-grant-read-access-to-all-databases-to-a-login and https://akawn.com/blog/2014/07/granting-read-only-access-to-multiple-databases-in-sql-server-2014/ and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/best-way-to-grant-read-all-permission-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: Obviously not :-). I'll try the third option as this seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks